# How to improve repeated use of a try statement in Python?

Tags: python, json, error-handling

I am trying to extract several elements from a JSON object which contains metadata about a song, using Python. To test if information is available, I am using a try statement for each metadata element. Also, for some string processing that I need to do later in my program, I am saving each value in a different variable.

Any suggestions on how to improve the following code in order to not make a try/except statement for each different metadata value?

```
if len(r['response']['songs']) is not 0:
    # Request information about the artist
    artist_desc_string = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/terms?api_key="+api_key+\
                         "&name="+artist+"&format=json"
    r2 = requests.get(artist_desc_string).json()

    # Extract information from the song JSON
    try:
        title = r['response']['songs'][0]['title']
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        title = "NULL"

    try:
        artist_name = r['response']['songs'][0]['artist_name']
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        artist_name = "NULL"

    try:
        artist_location = r['response']['songs'][0]['artist_location']['location'].replace(',','*')
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        artist_location = "NULL"

    try:
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you were just looking to handle a KeyError on the last element, you could look at `dict.get`, but since you are catching anything along the entire length of the lookup path, not really.  You could maybe put the paths in a list and loop over them, but that's only arguably more concise, and probably slower.

Comment: Just an observation: you can always assign that `r['response']['songs'][0]` to a single variable, seeing as to how it's used repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```
def get_value(d, keys):
    try:
        if keys:
            for i in range(len(keys)):
                key = keys[i]
                return get_value(d[key], keys[i+1:])
        return d
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        return "Null"


>>> d = {'person': {'name': {'first': 'aamir'}}}
>>> get_value(d, ['person', 'name', 'first'])
aamir
```

Comment: lol very simillar to my answer(except even more readable) :) +1

Comment: @JoranBeasley I just noticed it :P i was writing my own solution.

Comment: Upvoted you both.. Didn't really expect deeper attribs from what OP asked, but I like your solutions.

Comment: Looking into op question code `r['response']['songs'][0]` is a dictionary and can be stored in a single variable, the solution will work for single or multiple keys.

Answer (score 3):

something like this maybe?

```
def get_or_dont(d,list_of_keys):
    d2 = d
    while list_of_keys:
        try:
            d2 = d2[list_of_keys.pop(0)]
            if not list_of_keys: return d2
        except:
            break
    return "Null"

r = {'response':{
'a':5,
'b':{'6':{'5':3}},
'c':[1,2,3]
}}
print get_or_dont(r['response'],["b","6"])
```

Comment: bare `except`?  frowny face.

Comment: the list of exceptions is long... basically any exception should return a "Null"

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop with all possible attributes...

`attribs = {'title': None, 'artist_name':None, 'location': None, 'etc': None}
for key in attribs:
    try:
        attribs[key] = r['response']['songs'][0][key]
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        attribs[key] = "NULL"`

That way you only have to manage the dict *attribs* ...

As far as grabbing unexpected attributes, you could always get the keys of the JSON object and create more entries in attribs

Comment: this wouldnt be able to handle something like `r['response']['songs'][0]['artist_location']['location']` though right?